# What is an efficient way to calculate cost constrained by thresholds

Tags: python

I want to calculate cost of water expense of households constrained by certain thresholds:
Basically the thresholds are as follows:

- for the first 0-10 m3 it will cost $10
- for the subsequent 11-20 m3 it will cost $20
- for the subsequent 21-30 m3 it will cost $30
- for the subsequent >30 m3 it will cost $40

For example, if a household uses 40 m3 of water, it will be charged:

`(10*10) + (10*20) + (10*30) + (10*40) = $1000`

if a household uses 23 m3 of water, it will be charged:

`(10*10) + (10*20) + (3*30) = $390`

The only way I can think of is using if-conditionals. And I don't think that's the best way to calculate this.

Comment: What's wrong with using `if` statements? It will be the fastest and the shortest solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could also use a dictionary:

```
dic = {0:(0,10), 1:(100,20), 2:(300,30), 3:(600,40)}
```

Then you only need once an if-statement.

```
def costs(vol):
    interval = vol/10 # vol must be positive int
    if interval in dic:
        price = dic[interval]
        return price[0] + price[1]*(vol-price[1] + 10)
    else:
        return dic[3][0] + dic[3][1]*(vol-dic[3][1] + 10)
```

You can use the fact that the cost function is piecewise linear. Thus, you have to find out at which interval you are and use this as the key to your dictionary, where you save the cost at the beginning of each interval aswell as the increase of cost.

Comment: Wh..what kind of sorcery is this? Can you explain this to me?

Comment: @William your cost function is stepwise linear. Thus, you only have to know in which step you are. This you can find out with `interval = vol/10`. The cost value at the beginning of each step is also known: 0, 100, 300, 600 this is saved in the dict together with actual cost at this step.

Comment: Ahh, yeah yah, you put the initial cost based on the interval, damn..I wish I'm that clever. Good job!

Comment: As readability counts and DRY is important, I'd do `cost = lambda vol, offset, slope: offset + slope * (vol - slope + 10)`, or even the same in a function, and then do `...return cost(vol, *dic[interval])`.

Answer (score 0):

First define a list which will hold these limits in `(difference in volume, price)` format:

```
lst = [(10, 10), (10, 20), (10, 30), (None, 40)]
```

Note that the order matters. Here `None` stands for "no limit". And now the function:

```
def get_money(volume):
    if volume <= 0:
        return 0

    total = 0
    for diff, price in lst:
        if volume == 0:
            break

        if diff is None:
            total += volume * price
            volume = 0
        elif volume > diff:
            total += diff * price
            volume -= diff
        else:
            total += volume * price
            volume = 0

    return total
```

BTW: There is no way to solve this without using `if`. :)